# implementing BeanNameAware breaks Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.5 and I am trying to make a class implement `BeanNameAware`. **Without implementing this class my application works**.
When I implements it fails to start with error like :

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [mypackage.AccountSiebelDataHolder] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=accountSiebelDataHolder),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have a classe like this :

```
@Transactional
public abstract class DataHolder<T extends DbObject> implements BeanNameAware{

    private String beanName;

    ...

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
        this.beanName=name;

    }
}
```

And several class that extends this class :

```
public class AccountSiebelDataHolder extends DataHolder<AccountSiebel> {
 ...
}
```

bean are created in xml :

```
<bean id="accountSiebelDataHolder" class="mypackage.AccountSiebelDataHolder">
...
</bean>
```

I know that my beans are well instanciated because I see in the console every beans name.
The `setBeanName()` method is called. 
But right after that, it fails while autowiring (With or Without`@Qualifier` its the same)

I tried implements `BeanNameAware` in the childs class it gives me the same results.

Maybe it is important : these `Dataholder` class are instantiated by Spring root context. And then are injected in `@Controller` bean which are instanciated in @MVC context. But it works nice whithout `BeanNameAware`.

Comment: You have `@Transactional` which leads to proxy creation. Without interfaces a class based proxy is created by default, with interface a JDK dynamic proxy is created (interface based). Add `proxy-target-class="true"` to your `<tx:annotation-driven />` element to force the use of class-based proxies.

Comment: thanks that was the solution ! Maybe you can reply directly so I can accept yoru answer.

Comment: Added a bit more elaborate answer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises due to the `@Transactional`. Transactions are applied using AOP and by default [Spring uses proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies) to apply AOP.

Without an interface spring will create a class-based proxy using cglib. At runtime a dynamic subclass is created, this subclass is still a `DataHolder` instance.

Adding the interface will lead to the creation of a JDK Dynamic proxie which is interface. At runtime a dynamic class is created implementing all interfaces of the object to proxy. This leads to the class being a `BeanNameAware` instance and not an instance of `DataHolder` anymore.

To solve this force your transaction support to always use class-based proxies. For this set the `proxy-target-class` attribute on `<tx:annoation-driven />` to `true`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```